# tcpdump doesn't appear to call any libpcap's exported function

Tags: networking, network-interface, tcpdump, tcp-ip, dynamic-loading

Digging into `tcpdump` implementation, I can see that it actually loads the `libpcap.so` dynamic library in userspace.

However, by use of `strace`, I can't see any occurrence of calls to any function exported by libpcap.

Is the above an expected behaviour of tcpdump? Thank you.

```
root@eve-ng02:~# tcpdump --help
tcpdump version 4.9.2
libpcap version 1.7.4
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Edit: from received comments I tried with `ltrace` but it seems no call to dynamic library is done as well.

```
root@eve-ng02:~# ltrace tcpdump -i lo
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
    
^C--- SIGINT (Interrupt) ---

0 packets captured
126 packets received by filter
98 packets dropped by kernel
+++ exited (status 0) +++
root@eve-ng02:~#
```

Comment: `strace` is meant for system calls not function calls as far as I know.

Comment: If you are tracing library calls, then use `ltrace`.

Comment: ah ok, so how should I do to trace both syscalls and library calls ?

Answer (score 2):

`strace` shows only system calls. `ltrace` is a tool for showing library calls (see [Difference between system call and library call](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-system-call-and-library-call/)).

If you want to see both system calls AND library calls, you can add the `-S` flag for `ltrace` (*"Display system calls as well as library calls"*)

You can also add the `-k` to your `strace` (*"Print the execution stack trace of the traced processes after each system call"*) if your `strace` version supports it. It won't show all the library calls, but it will show you the execution trace of every system call, in which you can see which library triggered the system call.

```
17212 eventfd2(0, EFD_NONBLOCK)         = 3
 > /lib64/libc-2.31.so(eventfd+0x7) [0x117b87]
 > /usr/lib64/libpcap.so.1.10.1() [0xb8fa]
 > /usr/lib64/libpcap.so.1.10.1(pcap_create+0xaa) [0x10a9a]
 > /usr/sbin/tcpdump() [0x3efbf]
 > /usr/sbin/tcpdump() [0x3c891]
 > /lib64/libc-2.31.so(__libc_start_main+0xee) [0x3524c]
 > /usr/sbin/tcpdump() [0x3e149]
17212 socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(0 /* ETH_P_??? */)) = 4
 > /lib64/libc-2.31.so(__socket+0x7) [0x1190d7]
 > /usr/lib64/libpcap.so.1.10.1() [0xa0c0]
 > /usr/lib64/libpcap.so.1.10.1(pcap_activate+0x1c) [0x1191c]
 > /usr/sbin/tcpdump() [0x3f0d2]
 > /usr/sbin/tcpdump() [0x3c891]
 > /lib64/libc-2.31.so(__libc_start_main+0xee) [0x3524c]
 > /usr/sbin/tcpdump() [0x3e149]
```

Comment: 'ltrace -S tcpdump -n -i lo' actually shows only calls to syscalls and not to any dynamic libraries's function.

Comment: @CarloC check: [No output when running ltrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43213505/no-output-when-running-ltrace)

Comment: `root@eve-ng02:~# readelf -h /usr/sbin/tcpdump | grep Type
  Type:         DYN (Shared object file)`

So, according your link, there is no way to trace dynamic library calls. BTW my strace version doesn't support `-k` option.

Comment: `root@eve-ng02:~# strace -V

strace -- version 4.11`

Comment: @CarloC well, according to the answers in the link, it seems that your `tcpdump` doesn't support `ltrace`. And regarding `-k` for `strace`, check if it has the flag: `strace -h | grep -- -k`. Also the man pages of your `strace`, it might say seomthing such as: "this option is available only if `strace` is built with `libunwind`." If it does, you can check if it is compiled with this library: `ldd /usr/bin/strace | grep libunwind`.

Comment: `root@eve-ng02:~# strace -h | grep -- -k              
root@eve-ng02:~# 
root@eve-ng02:~# ldd /usr/bin/strace | grep libunwind
root@eve-ng02:~#`